# html form POST to _blank but changes to GET

Tags: html, forms, browser, wechat

In most browsers the following html works ok and `test_form.jsp` got `q=ok` and http method is POST:

```
    <form id="testForm" action="/test_form.jsp" method="POST" target="_blank">
        <input type="hidden" id="testKey" name="q" value="ok">
        <input type="submit" value="Test Post">
    </form>
```

But in some browsers such as WeChat (Weixin / MicroMessanger) embedded browser in iPhone, `test_form.jsp` got no parameters and http method is GET. So I have to add the following scripts as workaround:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("micromessenger") >= 0) {
    testForm.target = "";
}

--></script>
```

But our customers also report the issue outside WeChat.

Are there some browser settings that prohibit POST to _blank ?

Comment: I guess this is because WeChat browser does not have multi-window or multi-tab, which makes it have to "Open" `/test_form.jsp` in current window. For HTTP method is changed to GET, it looks like a browser bug.

Comment: find this agent `Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_12_4)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)++++Chrome/55.0.2883.95+Safari/537.36` also changes to GET. I don't think AppleWebKit or Chrome or Safari has such a bug.